# Handling post data with requests in python

Tags: python, post, authentication, http-post, python-requests

Can't login with my account in website with the following parameters:

```
token=...#by xpath
postdata={'token':token, 'arg1':'', 'arg2':'', 'name[user]': user, 'name[password]':password, 'arg3': 'Sign in'}
postresp=requests.post(url='http://example.com', data=postdata)
.
.
.
```

Should I change **name[user]** to `name%5Buser%5D` ?

Should I change **name[password]** to `name%5Bpassword%5D` ?

Should I change **Sign in** to `Sign+in` ?

**arg1** and **arg2** are blank. Should I remove them?

If not how can I change them? because I cant login to my account...

Comment: No you don't have to encode it. But I think you should send this header: Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Could you possibly post the answer and explain me more? Thanks

Comment: @Vincent Beltman And how about blank args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requests lib already encodes your dictionaries. But if you wanna do it yourself, you should use a string. For a dict try this:

```
postdata={
    'token':token,
    'arg1':'',
    'arg2':'',
    'name[user]': user, # I think this should be : instead of ,
    'name[password]':password,
    'arg3': 'Sign in'}
headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    # With this header you tell the server you're sending form params
}
postresp=requests.post(url='http://example.com', headers=headers, data=postdata)
```